# No access to the website from Azure Container Instance using a private network with custom DNS server

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances

I have Virtual Network with two subnets (A and B). Vnet is configured to use a custom DNS server. In one subnet (A) I have a web server which has an appropriate DNS configuration. If I create a VM inside subnet A and I try to open a website using DNS, then everything is working correctly. Subnet B is fully dedicated to Azure Container Instances. When I create a container group with one container (azure cli), and I try to connect to a website, I get an exception that page is not available.  It seems that my container instance is not using my custom DNS server assigned for the virtual network. Any ideas what may be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ACI is deployed to an existing vnet and the vnet is configured with the custom DNS server, ACI will not inherit the custom DNS servers. You need to deploy the ACI through YAML file and specify the DNS server in the specification of `dnsConfig`.

For example, below YAML file, to deploy an ACI with Nginx image in an existing vnet using network profile and configure custom DNS servers. Refer to [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/61488).

[image]

For more reference, you could read [YAML reference: Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-reference-yaml#containergroupproperties-object)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information. We found the same. Additionally this DNSconfig may be only set via yaml or rest api. Azure CLI doesn't support it.

Comment: BTW. This should be explicitly described in the documentation.

Comment: @AdamŁepkowski the closest we got was someone who raised a [github issue specifically for this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/61488), but then an ACI developer basically just said "yep we confirm this is the intended functionality" and completely disregarded them asking for the documentation to be updated. [Closest we got is this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-reference-yaml), which still isn't too specific and it's hard to follow (as of today)